Probability of Odd number of renewals
I am trying to solve the following problem:
For a renewal process with distribution $F(x)$ compute
$$
p(t) = P(\text{number of renewals in $(0,t]$ is odd})
$$
and find a expression when $F(t) = \int_{0}^{t} x e^{-x} dx$.
It is supposed to be requested $P(N(t) = 2k+1)$.Then we have
$$
P(N(t) = 2k+1) = F_{T_{2k+1}}(t) - F_{T_{2k+2}}(t)
$$
with $T_n$ the time until the $n-$th event occurs. Is there any other expression equivalent to this? Or what can be simplified more? In the case when $F(t)  =\int_{0}^{t} x e^{-x} dx$ we have
\begin{align*}
P(N(t) = 2k+1) & = \left( 1 - \sum_{i = 0}^{2k} \frac{t^{i} e^{-t}}{i!} \right) - \left( 1 - \sum_{i = 0}^{2k+1} \frac{t^{i} e^{-t}}{i!} \right)
\end{align*}
because $F(t)$ is the cdf of a $\operatorname{Gamma}(2,1)$. Is this correct? I appreciate any help or suggestions. Greetings
